# Rails 4 Has_one nested form - Error Unpermiited parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, has-one

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I have two models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :review, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :review, allow_destroy: true
end
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

They have a has_one relationship. The database has the product_id column in the reviews table.

My controller is straight forward on the new (@product = Product.new) and edit action has nothing. Here are my strong params:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, ..., review_attributes: [:id, :rating, :text, :author, :name] )
end
```

My form is as follows:

```
<%= form_for(@product, :html => {multipart: true, :class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
...

    <%= f.fields_for :review do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.hidden_field :author, :value => 'Yes' %>
          <%= ff.label :rating, "Enter a Rating" %>
          <%= ff.number_field :rating, class: "form-control input-md", min: 0, max: 5, step: 0.5 %>   
          <%= ff.label :name, "Title of Review" %>
          <%= ff.text_field :name, class: "form-control input-md" %>   
            <%= ff.label :text, "Review Description" %>
            <%= ff.text_area :text, class: "form-control" %>
    <% end %>
       <%= f.submit "Create Product", :class => 'btn btn-default btn-lg' %>
<% end %>
```

I cannot figure out why the nested form does not appear when I have the accepts_nested_attributes in the model, whether or not I need that accepts_nested_attributes, and why I get an error saying "unpermitted parameters: review" when I do not have the accepts_nested_attributes and submit the form. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps, you need to build the review object in the controller before the view renders...  Everything else you have there looks okay to me, I think you are missing the associated object when the form renders... I made an answer for you to accept if that is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller, try to build the review object in the method that is rendering that form...

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  @product.build_review
end
```

Comment: That worked.. Any ideas about why? I thought the accepts_nested_attributes takes care of the build?

Comment: nope, you have to build the object where you are accepting the attributes... `<%= f.fields_for :review do |ff| %>` that line... where you are saying, here are the fields for the `review` object... you have to have that object build in memory...  make sense?

Comment: Yes. Another issue I am having is with the edit action in the controller. The information for the review object does not populate the form fields. Any ideas there? Right not, my controller is just (def edit end).